# How to encode punctuation and delimiter characters in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I found in GWT, the method URL.encode() cannot encode punctuation and delimiter characters,is there a way to solve this? any idea is appreciated.

And I am wondering why GWT URL.encode() doesn't encode those characters? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course just lookup the character code in an [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/): `'` is hex `$27`
and then replace the character in the string with the corresponding escape sequence: e.g. `var='test'` will become `var=%27test%27`

Here's a [JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc0u0k67/) to test it

GWT does not encode it, because it is a valid character in a URL: so I wonder, why you would want to encode it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the string is actually dynamic, I need to escape all punctuation and delimiter character.

Comment: Then use [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `replace()` or `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 0):

`URL.encode()` simply defers to JavaScript's `encodeURI`.

If you want `encodeURIComponent`, use [`URL.encodePathSegment`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encodePathSegment-java.lang.String-)

(or use JsInterop)